# MongoDB copy a field to another collection with a foreign key

Tags: mongodb, copy, foreign-keys, database

I want to copy over the color from user collection to the Car collection. I'm using a foreign key which is userID.

```
> db.test1.User.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515f7db83f71d6bcb1c41a48"), "age" : 33, "Color" : "blue" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515f7dc03f71d6bcb1c41a49"), "age" : 52, "Color" : "red" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515f7dc43f71d6bcb1c41a4a"), "age" : 43, "Color" : "yellow" }


> db.test2.Car.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515f84883f71d6bcb1c41a54"), "speed" : 291, "userID" : ObjectId("515f7db83f71d6bcb1c41a48") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515f84883f71d6bcb1c41a55"), "speed" : 202, "userID" : ObjectId("515f7db83f71d6bcb1c41a49") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515f84883f71d6bcb1c41a56"), "speed" : 193, "userID" : ObjectId("515f7db83f71d6bcb1c41a4a") }
```

Here is my query

```
db.test1.User.find().forEach( 
function(x)
{
  db.test2.Car.update( { userID: x._id }, { $set: { color: x.color} } ) 
} );
```

I want this result:

```
> db.test2.Car.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515f84883f71d6bcb1c41a54"), "speed" : 291, "userID" : ObjectId("515f7db83f71d6bcb1c41a48"), "color" : "blue" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515f84883f71d6bcb1c41a55"), "speed" : 202, "userID" : ObjectId("515f7db83f71d6bcb1c41a49"), "color" : "red" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515f84883f71d6bcb1c41a56"), "speed" : 193, "userID" : ObjectId("515f7db83f71d6bcb1c41a4a"), "color" : "yellow" }
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you tell what is the real issue , Is it that you are not able to update or your userId is not matching ?

Answer (score 6):

There are several issues with your test set up:

- Case of field names does not match (you are referencing `color` instead of `Color` when copying)
- Only one of the example foreign keys matches in the target collection: `ObjectId('515f7db83f71d6bcb1c41a48')`
- Your update will only affect the first matching document for the "foreign key".  This would be fine for a 1:1 relationship, but not a 1:many

A corrected example taking the above into account (aside from the non-matching keys):

```
db.test1.User.find().forEach( 
    function(x) {
        db.test2.Car.update(
            // query 
            { userID: x._id },

            // update 
            { $set: { color: x.Color} },

            // options:
            { "multi" : true } // Update all matching documents
        );
    }
);
```

Which results in setting `{color:blue}` for the only foreign key that actually matches in the sample documents:

```
db.test2.Car.find()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("515f84883f71d6bcb1c41a55"),
    "speed" : 202,
    "userID" : ObjectId("515f7db83f71d6bcb1c41a49")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("515f84883f71d6bcb1c41a56"),
    "speed" : 193,
    "userID" : ObjectId("515f7db83f71d6bcb1c41a4a")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("515f84883f71d6bcb1c41a54"),
    "color" : "blue",
    "speed" : 291,
    "userID" : ObjectId("515f7db83f71d6bcb1c41a48")
}
```

Comment: I have a similar situation. But some of my car documents have _id as String and some have _id as ObjectId type. Above mentioned solution is not working for ObjectId. Please help.

Comment: @truekiller Please post a new question with sample documents and details of your issue (what you've tried, what you outcome you expect, and a description of what currently isn't working).

Comment: i have posted a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53261010/copy-a-field-from-one-collection-to-another-in-mongodb-with-foreign-key-as-mixed Please have a look.

Answer (score 4):

Here are my two cents: you can drop "function(x)". I prefer the following syntax:

```
db.source_collection_name.find().forEach(
  doc=>
      db.target_collection_name.update(
        {"_id": doc._id},
        {$set: {"field_to_update": doc.field}}
      )
)
```

In your case, something like this should work:

```
db.test1.User.find().forEach(
  doc=> 
    db.test2.Car.update( 
      { "userID": doc._id }, 
      { $set: { "color": doc.Color} } 
    ) 
);
```