# Copy a field from one collection to another in mongodb with foreign key as mixed type

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

Although i have found a similar question on stackOverFlow [MongoDB copy a field to another collection with a foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846376/mongodb-copy-a-field-to-another-collection-with-a-foreign-key/15870200?noredirect=1#comment93378647_15870200)

I want to copy a field `name` from `userdetails` collection to `user` collection where userId in userDetails equals _id in user.

**user** collection

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b97743bbff66e0be66283cc"),                                                                                                                                                       
  "username" : "mmi_superadmin",                                                                                                                                                                                     
  "accId" : "acc1"                                                                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                                                                                    
{                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  "_id" : "c21d580ea3ca5c7a1664bd5feb57f0c8",                                                                                                                                                             
  "username" : "client",                                                                                                                                                                               
  "accId" : "acc1"                                                                                                                                                               
}
```

**userDetail** collection

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b97743bbff66e0be66283cd"),                                                                                                                                                    
  "userId" : "5b97743bbff66e0be66283cc",                                                                                                                                                         
  "name" : "mmi_superadmin"                                                                                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                                                                                                                    
{                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  "_id" : "5bab8a60ef86bf90f1795c44",                                                                                                                                                                  
  "userId" : "c21d580ea3ca5c7a1664bd5feb57f0c8",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  "name" : "RAHUL KUMAR TIWARI"                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

Here is my query :

```
db.userDetails.find().forEach(
function(x) {
  db.user.update( {_id :x.userId}, {$set: {name:x.name}});
}
);
```

This query is partially working. It only updates `user` documents where _id is of type string. User document with _id as ObjectId are not getting updated.

Comment: Ye Olde JavaScript hack.  `{ _id: new ObjectId(x.userId.valueOf()) }` As the `valueOf()` is going to return the "string" whether it's a string or an `ObjectId`. And of course we're casting to `ObjectId`. Strongly Advising that you actually at least normalize ALL `_id` values to be `ObjectId`. And that means deleting the documents where it is not since `_id` is immutable.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your documents _id's (because in your example some _id's is not valid documents _id's. for example `c21d580ea3ca5c7a1664bd5feb57f0c8` not a mongo _id) and use this query:

```
let usersIds = [];
db.user.find({"_id": {$type: 7}}).forEach(doc => {
    usersIds.push(doc._id + '')

    db.userDetail.find({
        userId: {
            $in: usersIds
        }
    }).forEach(doc => {
        db.user.update(
            {
                "_id": ObjectId(doc.userId)
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    "name": doc.name
                }
            },
            { 
                multi: false,
                upsert: false
            }
        )
    })

})
```

if you have any question feel free to ask

Comment: Some of the documents in user tables have application generated Id and i can not change those id. This is where all the complication lies. Else the query i have mentioned in the question would have worked.

Comment: in this case you can run two different queries:
first your query for string _id's
second second for objectId's 
Please check updated answer